# Setting width of table cells with CSS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

I have a HTML table where I must set the overall width and want to make sure the label column doesn't get too wide.

It works as expected in Firefox 4, but IE 9 seems to completely ignore the with property.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
table,th,td { border: solid 1px; border-collapse: collapse; }
th.caption { width: 700px; }
.label { width: 100px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr><th class="caption" colspan=2>Caption</th></tr>
<tr><td class="label">Label</td><td>Stuff...</td></tr>
<tr><td class="label">Label</td><td>Stuff...</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Add `<!DOCTYPE html>` as the very first line to get Standards Mode (not directly related to your problem, but you should definitely do it unless you like IE9 pretending to be IE5 - [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode)).
- Set the overall width of the table on `table` instead of `th.caption`.

**See:** http://jsbin.com/icafo3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
table,th,td { border: solid 1px; border-collapse: collapse; }
table { width: 700px; }
.label { width: 100px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr><th class="caption" colspan=2>Caption</th></tr>
<tr><td class="label">Label</td><td>Stuff...</td></tr>
<tr><td class="label">Label</td><td>Stuff...</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just adding the <!DOCTYPE html> is enough to make it work in both browsers. Thanks!

Comment: I guess it was related after all then :) I think I got a little confused about the desired end result.